# Float over iframes html

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, css-float

Is it possible to float a nav bar over a iframe here is the code that i have so  far?

the nav bar as you will be is in the html page and contains buttons that trigger the iframe to go to the next page etc.

Any ideas?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Fraud Protection - Course</title>
<style>
    .backbutton[type="button"] {
        border: 0;
        background: url("back.png") no-repeat;
        text-indent: -9999em;
        line-height:3000;
        width: 100px;
        height: 35px;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
        .nextbutton[type="button"] {
        border: 0;
        background: url("next.png") no-repeat;
        text-indent: -9999em;
        line-height:3000;
        width: 100px;
        height: 35px;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
            .savebutton[type="button"] {
        border: 0;
        background: url("save.png") no-repeat;
        text-indent: -9999em;
        line-height:3000;
        width: 100px;
        height: 35px;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <iframe src="" width="100%" class="naviframe" id="contentFrame" hieght="100%"></iframe>
    <div id="navDiv">
     <input type="button" class="backbutton" id="butPrevious" onclick="doPrevious();" value="<- Previous"/>
        <input type="button" class="nextbutton" value="Next ->" img src="/images/Btn.PNG" id="butNext" onclick="doNext();"/>
        <input type="button" class="savebutton" value="Save Progress"  img src="/images/Btn.PNG" id="butExit" onclick="doExit();"/>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You have to position the element to be floated, as `absolute` with negative margin.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/6XXt8/)

Comment: Why not simply use position rules: `top, right, bottom, left`? Instead of setting some margin I mean, `position:absolute` is ofcourse needed.

Comment: top, and similar starts their positive from their nearest relative container, unlike margins, which is self dependant.

Comment: Basically i need the html page to float over the top of the iframe so that the iframe has 100% of the screen? 

Confusing i know lol...

Comment: @Starx Please explain your comment. Margins are acting precise in the same way as top, left.. etc.

Comment: @Teemu, margin is element dependent, if I do margin-top: -50px, It will go up from its original position, but if you do margin: 0; It will remain the same. But, in case of top, left, ..., top: 0; jumps the elements to the nearest relatively positioned element, by default its body.

Comment: @Starx AFAIK, by default, positioned elements have a value `0px` set for `top` and `left`. Margins are calculated according this position.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with position: absolute;

Answer (score 0):

Simple CCS for your nav bar:

```
.navDiv{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

Just change the values for `top` and `left` as you need. In this case, these values are relative to `document.body`.

You have a misstypo in `height`-attribute for `iframe` in your code. Also it seems that percentage is not allowed for `iframe` height, you have to use some other unit instead.